# Evernote notes overwritten when updated externally

Tags: c#, api, overwrite, evernote

I'm building an app that updates Evernote notes via the Windows C# API. I've noticed an issue where a note that is updated by my app in between sync's in the Windows desktop app (for example) is overwritten.

This also happens when a note is updated in between sync's via another app (e.g. iPhone). To explain this further I've outlined the steps to reproduce the problem using the Windows and iPhone apps.

Please note that in order to repro this there must be a delay in between syncs in the Windows app. Within the app the sync interval can be changed in `Tools` > `Options` > `Synchronization`:

1. Create note with a reminder in the Windows app
2. Manually sync Evernote (Windows app)
3. Sync this note to another device, say the iPhone app
4. Add a tag to the note & sync (iPhone app)
5. Complete the reminder in the Windows app
6. Manually sync Evernote (Windows app)

If the above steps "work", once the Windows app is sync'd the reminder will be active (i.e. not complete) and the tag will be added.

I understand that this sort of scenario is unlikely to happen in a real usage scenario of Evernote, however as I am updating notes regularly via the API the chances of it happening or much more likely.

The ideal solution would be to update specific fields instead of the whole note, however I could see any way to do this.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you call [NoteStore#updateNote](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_updateNote), try to set `guid` and only attributes you want to update and leave the rest unset.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i have tried that and unfortunately it still occurs.  I suspect this is something deeper rooted with the way Evernote update the notes on their end as it happens when using their apps

Comment: Can you provide details or code snippet that describe how you construct the note and call APIs?